# Crear diccionario a partir de archivo .csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, diccionarios

soy nuevo en Python.

Tengo el siguiente dataset, archivo `.csv`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero crear un diccionario que tenga el siguiente tipo de salida:

```
{
"Pais1": {"time": [1/22/20, 1/23/20,...], "cases": [0, 0,...],
"Pais2": {"time": [1/22/20, 1/23/20,...], "cases": [0, 0,...],
...
}
```

Cómo podeis ver en el archivo .csv hay paises que no tienen `Province/State` pero todos tienen `Country/Region`. Así que he realizado lo siguiente para agrupar los datos:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(path_co)
df = df.groupby(['Country/Region']).sum()
```

De modo que he obtenido el siguiente fichero con los casos sumados por pais y fecha:

```
                  Lat      Long     1/22/20     1/23/20     1/24/20     1/25/20     1/26/20     1/27/20 ...
Country/Region                                                          
Afghanistan     33.939110   67.709953   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Albania     41.153300   20.168300   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Algeria     28.033900   1.659600    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Andorra     42.506300   1.521800    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Angola  -11.202700  17.873900   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Antigua and Barbuda     17.060800   -61.796400  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Argentina   -38.416100  -63.616700  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Armenia     40.069100   45.038200   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Australia   -256.850200     1130.843900     0   0   0   0   4   5   5   6   9   9   12  12  12
Austria     47.516200   14.550100   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Azerbaijan  40.143100   47.576900   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Bahamas     25.025885   -78.035889  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Mi pregunta es, creando un diccionario vacío:

```
d = dict()
```

Cómo puedo volcar los datos en el?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un dataframe pandas tiene el método `.to_dict()`, que ofrece muchas posibilidades de cara a transformar el contenido del dataframe en un diccionario.

Para el caso que planteas creo que la mejor opción sería la modalidad "split", pero mira el anexo al final de la pregunta para otras opciones, pues quizás prefieras alguna de las otras.

En la modalidad `"split"`, harías lo siguiente:

```
aux = df.drop(columns=["Lat", "Long"]).to_dict(orient="split")
```

(He quitado las columnas "Lat" y "Long" que parece que no querías). El resultado es un diccionario con solo tres campos:

- `"index"` contendría en tu caso una lista con los nombres de las ciudades
- `"columns"`  contendría en tu caso otra lista con los nombres de las columnas (las fechas)
- `"data"` contiene una lista de listas, es decir una matriz, con los números que hay dentro del dataframe. Cada elemento de esa lista son los contenidos de una fila (otra lista).

Así pues, en base a lo que tenemos en `aux` podemos crear el diccionario que deseas así:

```
d = {}
for i,pais in enumerate(aux["index"]):
  d[pais]={"time": aux["columns"], "cases": aux["data"][i]}
```

Con el resultado en `d`:

```
{
    'Afghanistan': {
        'time': ['1/22/20', '1/23/20', '1/24/20', ...],
        'cases': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]},
    'Albania': {
        'time': ['1/22/20', '1/23/20', '1/24/20', ...],
        'cases': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]},
    #...
    'Bahamas': {
        'time': ['1/22/20', '1/23/20', '1/24/20', ...], 
        'cases': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
}
```

## Anexo

Hay más posibilidades:

- Que cada clave del diccionario sea un nombre de columna (una fecha en tu caso), y su valor sea otro diccionario cuyas claves son el índice (los países)

  Esto se logra simplemente con `df.to_dict()` y un ejemplo del resultado sería:

  ```
    {'Lat': {
      'Afghanistan': 33.93911,
      'Albania': 41.1533,
       # ...
      'Bahamas': 25.025885},
     'Long': {
      'Afghanistan': 67.709953,
      'Albania': 20.1683,
       # ...
      'Bahamas': -78.035889},
     '1/22/20': {
      'Afghanistan': 0,
      'Albania': 0,
       # ...
      'Bahamas': 0},
    # Etc... (resto de fechas)
    }
  ```
- Que cada clave del diccionario sea en cambio el índice (los países) y cada valor sea otro diccionario cuyas claves son los nombres de columna (las fechas).

  Esto se logra con `df.to_dict(orient="index")` y un ejemplo del resultado sería:

  ```
  {'Afghanistan': {
    'Lat': 33.93911,
    'Long': 67.709953,    
    '1/22/20': 0,
     # ... etc
    },
  'Albania': {
    'Lat': 41.1533,
    'Long': 20.1683     
    '1/22/20': 0,
     # ... etc
    },
  # Etc... resto de países
  }
  ```
- Obtener un diccionario cuyas claves son los nombres de las columnas y cuyos valores son simplemente una lista con los contenidos de la columna (en este caso no aparecen en el resultado los nombres de las ciudades).

  Se obtiene con `df.to_dict(orient="list")` y un ejemplo del resultado sería:

  ```
  {
    'Lat': [33.93911, 41.1533, 28.0339, 42.5063, -11.2027, 17.0608, -38.4161, 40.0691, -256.8502, 47.5162, 40.1431, 25.025885],
    'Long': [67.709953, 20.1683, 1.6596, 1.5218, 17.8739, -61.7964, -63.6167, 45.0382, 1130.8439, 14.5501, 47.5769, -78.035889],
    '1/22/20': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    '1/23/20': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    '1/24/20': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    '1/25/20': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    '1/26/20': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0],
    '1/27/20': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0],
    # ...
  }
  ```

Y aún hay más posibilidades. Mírate [DataFrame.to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

Comment: Perdona, al ejecutar el código ha funcionado y me ha mostrado el diccionario. Sin embargo, lo he vuelto a ejecutar y ahora me dice ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Comment: ¿Qué línea te da ese error? Sin más información...

Comment: Es extraño porque he vuelto a limpiar todo y no me da el error. Parece como aleatorio... si vuelve a salir te lo mando :)